# How to check the presence of a DOM element in protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

Just want to click the **log off** link if it exists. No action if that link is not present.

Here is the code:

```
browser.get(browser.baseUrl + 'login');

var lnkLogOff = element(by.linkText('Log off'));
if (lnkLogOff.isPresent()) lnkLogOff.click();
```

It appears nothing is wrong. But I got a `NoSuchElementError` when the link is not on page.

What is the correct way to *check the presence of an element* in protractor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`isElementPresent()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.isElementPresent):

```
var locator = by.linkText('Log off');
browser.isElementPresent(locator).then(function (present) {
    if (present) {
        element(locator).click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code, looks like you are not waiting for element to be presented.

```
var waitElementToBeShown = function (elm) {
browser.wait(function () {
    return elm.isPresent();
},15000);
browser.wait(function () {
    return elm.isDisplayed();
},15000);
```

};

1st part corresponds for the presents of the element in the DOM, 
2nd part corresponds for an ability to click on it

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? Where should the locator go in your code?

Comment: var elem = element(by.linkText('Log off'));
waitElementToBeShown(elem);
elem.click();